# wmts (GeoTiff) for a Mapbox-GL source

Tags: geoserver, geotiff, mapbox-gl

I am trying to use a wmts (from GeoServer of a GeoTiff) for a Mapbox-GL source. Mapbox-GL is able to create the source and the layer without any error. However, the layer is not rendered, and GeoServer is never queried for the tiles.

```
map.on('load', function() {

    // Create raster layer from GeoServer
    map.addSource('rasterTest', {
        'type': 'raster',
        'tiles': 'http://localhost:32769/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?SERVICE=WMTS&REQUEST=GetTile&LAYER=enview:sample&TILEMATRIX=EPSG:900913:{z}&TILEMATRIXSET=EPSG:900913&format=image%2Fpng&TileCol={x}&TileRow={y}',
        'tileSize': 256,
    });

    map.addLayer({
        'id':1,
        'source': 'rasterTest',
        'type': 'raster',
        'visibility': 'visible',
        'source-layer': 'rasterTest',
    });

    console.log('map:');
    console.log(map);

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got 'tiles' listed as an option to addSource. I don't think that's valid for a raster source - see [docs here](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-style-spec/#sources) . Instead you need an 'url' property.

The next gotcha is that the 'url' property is not directly an URL pattern as with many mapping libs, but the URL of a TileJSON doc (not enough rep to link, sorry!), which contains the pattern. This isn't properly doc'd at the link above.

Here's a minimal WMTS TileJSON doc I got to work with Mapbox GL JS 0.15.0: https://gist.github.com/georgemarrows/e6eba8207281a93a0fc1

Answer (score 0):

Change the "source-layer" with the wmts LAYER name.

`'source-layer': 'enview:sample'` or `'source-layer': 'sample'`

```
//modified source 
map.on('load', function() {

    // Create raster layer from GeoServer
    map.addSource('rasterTest', {
        'type': 'raster',
        'tiles': 'http://localhost:32769/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?SERVICE=WMTS&REQUEST=GetTile&LAYER=enview:sample&TILEMATRIX=EPSG:900913:{z}&TILEMATRIXSET=EPSG:900913&format=image%2Fpng&TileCol={x}&TileRow={y}',
        'tileSize': 256,
    });

    map.addLayer({
        'id':'rasterTest',
        'source': 'rasterTest',
        'type': 'raster',
        'visibility': 'visible',
        'source-layer': 'enview:sample' //'rasterTest',
    });

})
```